# How to merge/smoothen the edges in a cylinder?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting

In a cylindrical object, the edges of the object are showing up in a particular area as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: Cylinder with edges]

How to smoothen the part of the object so that the color merges with the rest of the object and the edges do not show up separately? I have tried using Smooth modifier but it is deforming the entire object.

Comment: I think your normals are flipped try going into edit mode, select all the faces and press Shift+N. If this does not work then please share a screenshot of your object in edit mode so I can check out the mesh`s geometry.Share the file too please.

Comment: Hi, that didn't work. Here is a screenshot in edit mode - https://imgur.com/a/rowz9OU
Here's the fbx file - https://we.tl/t-Z7AEiVtBiU

Comment: thanks, but could you also share your file so I could show the process of fixing your problem

Comment: Yes, here's the blender file for this model - https://we.tl/t-SHEXjYEcYM

Comment: This model`s topology is appalling :( this problem can only be fixed by starting over. There are so many overlapping edges and triangles.It is impossible to continue working with your mesh.

Comment: i made a small tutorial for you how you could fix the topology (but just the "wrong placed vertices") for the rest, just check Robin's answer. The tutorial is here: https://youtu.be/TfLnTy8lW9g If you don't want your model on that page, just tell me, then i will delete it.

Comment: You can use the model for the video, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things going on...

Starting from your .fbx, as imported..

(Left, below) Behind your label-object, there is an identical section of the tube separated from the rest, (so its normals are discontinuous).

**Fix**: <kbd>M</kbd> > Merge > By Distance, with a near-0 threshold

(Right, below) Much of the tube has its custom-normals inverted.

**Fix**: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> Normals.. > Recalculate Outside

[image]

(Below) After recalculating the normals (left), you can see they are twisted. Under the Data tab, 'Normals' panel, you can leave 'Auto Smooth' checked...

**Fix**: Under the 'Geometry Data' panel, you can 'Clear Custom Split Normals Data' (right), without doing the model any harm.

[image]

Before and after the last correction:

[image]

Comment: I have to agree with @Ribbit12, the topo could be more economical, but assuming your job is to return the package in the shape you found it, this should be workable.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these videos:

**Part 1**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17xChiCEtkb8piA6KtMuNocFOCkJ38Lvw/view

**Part 2**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14cw7E39CvW0yIQiqkFXcLiSuxu6Gfsd7/view

**Part 3(optional)**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11DXgt7sxcAoaSCuqdqtA87LwS8kLaIdE/view

Sorry for the inconvenience of sending the videos through google drive. Each video is like 50MB I was not able to upload it in stack exchange, sorry :(

**Final Result:**

[image]

[image]

**Edited File:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y89fEJGO69RYt0e6pyFfw7RcWEYu9KLU/view

Comment: hmmm...ok, so you could split them up, so that they get smaller and/or size them down. There are some online tools for that. like this: http://gifgifs.com/resizer/ or just search for online gif resizer

Comment: sorry, no luck it says I can`t upload a file that is above 35MB.

Comment: Can you please share the edited file for reference?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y89fEJGO69RYt0e6pyFfw7RcWEYu9KLU/view